# getting value from another activity and return result without close current activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I got a listview, in every row i need to get user status from another class is online or offline so

Here is the scenario

> i send another activity an id;
>
> activity b process and returns a processed value
>
> so i get the value like online or offline,

its not problem with startActivityForResult for 1 request

but if i send 10 rows , cpu gets trouble

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)* in the main activity where listview is shown and from the other class; where status is getting processed, send status as a message ([Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html)) parameter - and in onHandle(Message msg){} method of the Hanlder - update only the list item whose status is changed. 
 *Note: you should do proper null checks on handler instances and also on the list item shown respectively in background class and foreground activity - So that if activity is not shown and background process is still running no exceptions are thrown.